# JavaScript js file too large - crashing WebStorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I'm trying to include a JavaScript library in my Cordova project in WebStorm, but every time I include the JS file it crashes. Also, when I try to open the file in Sublime it barely works - there are probably hundreds of thousands of lines of JavaScript in the file.

[Here it is](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jvail/spatiasql.js/master/js/spatiasql.js)

How can I get this library to play nicely?

Comment: From the README file of the source code: `(be patient, loading the js and database file takes some time).`

Comment: I said that it keeps crashing -  I have patience. I would really appreciate if you would not down vote the question based on the fact that it is not patience I am lacking.

Comment: Have you tried compressing the file using something like http://jscompress.com/?

Comment: Haha yes I just tried using that site to compress it. It told me "this file is too large to compress". Go figure.

Comment: Well it is an 8 mb file. Try minifying it locally with https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS. There is a `Usage` section down there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### thing 1

Change you code inspection settings. With smaller files, you can leave on all sorts of inspections you never really use; not so with large files. (**hint:** right-click the guy-with-a-hat icon in IntelliJ products)

#### thing 2

Tune your VM options to give it more memory. ([this link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827537-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties) will get you started)

#### thing 3

Obviously, I am obligated to try to talk you into refactoring the single, massive file into smaller js files. I know from experience that this isn't always practical, so I'm going to assume you've already tried that and decided it's not in the project's best interest.

Comment: I assumed not. About the only time I've seen js that large is when some massive third-party libs are compiled, minified, then re-uglified. No one **ever** does that to their own code.

Comment: I had a similar situation where I inherited a project that was processed this way: whoever built the code compiled about a dozen third-party libs into one god-file of a js :( I tried refactoring, but the commitment it was taking just didn't fit into the project timeline.

Comment: Would it be an option to include this in the header?

<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jvail/spatiasql.js/master/js/spatiasql.js"></script>

I know we do this for angular hosted on CDNs and whatnot, but would this be the same idea?

Comment: _if I'm fully understanding yor comment:_ That will work in specific situations, but all it really does is break-out the js from the html\php, which makes working on anything other than the js much easier. However, if you ever need to work on the js - which you almost certainly will - you'll still need to go into your god-file.

Comment: About splitting the file, does this violate licenses? :/

Comment: Really depends on the license, but that would be REALLY restrictive if it's the case :/ Regardless of license, you may run into a situation where you bang your keyboard and yell "_ahhh, this file is compiled in such a way that refactoring it takes more time than I'd budgeted for the **whole** project!_"

Comment: @kevinard Why am I able to include, say, 
<script src=htt://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js></script>, in the header and use its js and not be able to do the same with my library?

Comment: Yeah, you can certainly do that with this js. Is it throwing some error when you try?

Comment: I've got it working. I simply referenced it from the GitHub site its hosted at. However, I am supposed build a self sufficient app even when not connected to the internet - so, I will develop with the "CDN" then include the file afterwards. Problem solved. Thanks for your help!